# What does [0] of an input variable achieve?

Tags: python

```
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

while True:
 x = input()
 if x[0] == "A":
 y[0] += int(x[2:])
```

Could someone explain to me what this code means? X isn't a list, right? So how do you do [0] of it?

Comment: Strings are indexable

Comment: `x` is a `str`, `str` objects are sequences like lists, tuples, bytes, bytearray, ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input()` asks the user for text input. Text is returned as and stored in a variable with a data format (type) called a string, which is just a string of characters.

A string (`str`) is indexable:

```
s = '12345'
print(s[2:])  # prints 345
```

In general, `[x:y:s]` is indexing something with a 'slice'. `x` is the start, `y` is the end and `s` is the step size. Note that the start is included, but the end is not, so it's "starting at `x`, up to `y`, in steps of `s`". And indexing in Python, like most languages, starts at 0, not at 1.

For example:

```
print(s[0])     # prints 1
print(s[1::2])  # prints 24
print(s[:2])    # prints 12
print(s[::2])   # prints 135
```

Many data types are indexable with numbers and slices: lists, tuples, strings, arrays, DataFrames, etc. Some data types allow for indexing with other types as well, for example the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = input()
```

According to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), the input() function returns a string:

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
> without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
> converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
> that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised. Example:

Therefore, the value of x is the user's input.

> So how do you do [0] of it?

`x[0]` return the first character (at the index 0) of `x`.

```
if x[0] == "A":
    y[0] += int(x[2:])
```

This code will check if the first character (at the index 0) of `x` is "a", if yes, the first element of `y` (`y[0]`) will be added by the value of the integer value of `x[2:]`, which is the string after the second character of x.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the comment above, 'strings are indexable' means that accessing the 0th element of a `str` will give you the first character of the string (and 1st element the second letter, and so on).

So in the program above, if the user enter enters 'Aardvark' the `if` statement will evaluate to `True`, but if they enter 'Bear' it will evaluate to `False`.

the `if` statement will throw an `IndexError` only if the string is empty (i.e. the user pressed Enter without typing anything).

Answer (score 0):

You can think of string in Python as a list of characters/alphabet

```
>>> site = "stackoverflow"
>>> for index, character in enumerate(site):
...     print(f"Position of '{character}' in site is: {index}")
...
Position of 's' in site is: 0
Position of 't' in site is: 1
Position of 'a' in site is: 2
Position of 'c' in site is: 3
Position of 'k' in site is: 4
Position of 'o' in site is: 5
Position of 'v' in site is: 6
Position of 'e' in site is: 7
Position of 'r' in site is: 8
Position of 'f' in site is: 9
Position of 'l' in site is: 10
Position of 'o' in site is: 11
Position of 'w' in site is: 12

>>> for index, character in enumerate(site):
...     print(f"Position of '{character}' in site is: {index}")

>>> site[5:]  # taking slice of string - from index 5 to the end
'overflow'
```

You can refer to this for more in-depth: [How To Index and Slice Strings in Python 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3)

Explanation of your code:

```
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

while True:
    x = input()  # say, user inputs A2123
    if x[0] == "A":  # x[0] is the character value at 0th index which is "A"
        # x[2:] is slice of x from 2nd index to end, i.e. "123" (a string value).
        # So int("123") will covert it into 123 (an integer value)
        y[0] += int(x[2:])
```